# Reset an iMac to factory without passwords

Tags: mac

I got gifted an IMac from a friend they asked me to delete everything. It didn’t have an initial password to enter so I thought it was fine. To delete it’s requesting the admin password which they don’t remember. She said I can just delete everything it’s okay she has all her stuff backed up and on new iMac. So is there a way to delete everything and ability to sign in with my apple id and password without hers?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  Have you searched for previous answers to similar questions?

Comment: There are quite a few passwords in play. Do you have a picture of the screen when it asks you for a password or is this a more theoretical question at this point - how would I prepare a mac to erase and transfer to a new owner?

Answer (score 1):

First you'll need to turn off your iMac. Then press the **power** button and immediately hold down the **Control** and **R** keys until you see the Apple logo or spinning globe icon.

Release the keys and shortly afterward you should see the macOS Utilities window appear.
[image]

In this are four options: **Restore from Time Machine Backup**, **Reinstall macOS**, **Get Help Online** and **Disk Utility**. Click on the last one (Disk Utility) and then select Continue.

Next, you'll see a list of all the HDs currently attached to your Mac. In the left column are the names of each drive, while in the main panel are the details of the selected drive.

Look under the Internal section for your main drive. This is often called **Macintosh HD** and appears at the top of the list. Click on it so that it's highlighted, then click the **Erase** button from the options in the main panel. Use the same format suggested by the Erase on for your HD.

Once you are done, come back again to the window macOS Utilities and from there select Reinstall macOS. All should go good in 25-30 minutes as it downloads from the internet.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to Ask Different. I'm sure we can help you. If you have an internet connection you can use the method described [here](https://www.macworld.co.uk/how-to/mac/reset-mac-without-password-3680521/). This requires you to erase the existing internal disk drive. A summary of the link is to shut down your iMac and then restart in recovery mode. You'll see a screen like an image shown below.

[image]

Select the last option: Disk Utility. After finishing with Disk Utility go back to the macOS Utilities menu and select the 2nd menu item: Reinstall macOS. More thorough directions are given in the link. Be sure to read it.